# slow Inference time for Neural Net

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, libtorch

I have written a simple Fully connected Neural Network in Pytorch. I saved the model and loaded it in C++ using LibTorch but my inference time is pretty slow for my application field. Inference time right now is about 10 ms. Is it normal or am I doing something wrong?

I measured the inference time on python only first. then to maybe make it faster I loaded the network on C++ but it didn't help.

Here is the code for network

```
class network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(network,self).__init__()
        input_nodes = 362
        hidden_nodes1 = 50
        hidden_nodes2 = 30
        output_nodes = 1

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_nodes,hidden_nodes1)
    nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc1.weight)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=hidden_nodes1)

    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_nodes1,hidden_nodes2)
    nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc2.weight)
    self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features = hidden_nodes2)

    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_nodes2,output_nodes)
    nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc3.weight)

    self.out_act = nn.Sigmoid();

def forward(self,X):
    X = F.relu(self.bn1(self.fc1(X)))
    X = self.fc2(X)
    X = F.dropout2d(X,p=0.3)
    X = F.relu(X)
    X = self.fc3(X)
    out = self.out_act(X)
    return out
```

I want inference to somewhat take around 0.01 milliseconds.

Comment: How are you measuring the timings? If you could provide a working code, it would be nice.

Comment: Are you getting this inference time on a gpu or a cpu? I am facing a similar problem and want inference on an image in preferably 50 ms with mobilenet architecture.

Comment: @Berriel I am measuring the time to execute the forward function of the network

Comment: _(Sorry for the late comment...)_ : Did you try switching your network in to evaluation mode by calling `eval()` before inference?

Answer (score 1):

How much data did you use for the inference? If it is only a few data points, I think there will be no much difference in execution time between python and C++. Maybe try with much more data?

Also, the architecture you are using is straightforward; it can probably run in CPU very well for inference. Don't forget to give feedback with your tests! I also want to know what is happening. :)

Comment: In regards to my use of this network. I just provide a single input for inference rather than a batch of inputs. I can't use a batch as my next input depends upon the inference from the previous one. Also, I am not working with images so I don't think I need a deeper network.

Comment: I see. I did not make myself clear: the deeper architecture is just to see what happens with execution time, but I don't think it makes any sense now. Maybe it is related to your system? Are you tracking the execution time exactly in the same manner on both C++ and Python? Try to track time not on a single example, but on 1000, for example, on both Python and C++ and check the difference...

Comment: Yeah I will try that and will let you know the results.

Comment: I tried running the inference on a batch of 1000 inputs the runtime was around 72ms for the batch in whole.

Comment: I think the 10ms you reported could be due to the overhead of loading the model, stacking function parameters, etc... But when you see the runtime for a batch, this overhead is not significant compared to the execution of 1000 inputs. The 72ms is for the C++ implementation, right?

Answer (score 0):

Libtorch is indeed slow than pytorch.